# Can AJAX read files with custom extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have files with extensions **.cst** in my localhost server. I was thinking if AJAX can load them. So my question is can AJAX load files with custom extension ? If yes, how ? If no, any alternative such that we shall get the content of the file on page load ?

My ajax call for loading the file load.cst :

```
 $.get("load.cst", function(data) {
   console.log(data) 
 });
```

Comment: Did you make a call to the file and see what happens?

Comment: it depend on what's in the file. if it's a simple text file with a custom extension, I don't see any issues. But if it's something else, we can't be sure.

Comment: Yes I tried !!! Nothing happens. I checked for errors in the code, but everything was alright !

Comment: I tried, with a file named ad load.cst, that has only "Load me" as its content, but it didn't load !

Comment: Okay so what is the code? Show the Ajax call....!

Comment: Could you please stop with the exclamation point, it looks like you are yelling at us and we're just trying to help.

Comment: Yay sure its jquery ajax

Comment: So show it....!

Comment: So `console.log(data)` did not show the text? Add an error handler

Comment: Start by typing `http://load.cst` on your web browser and see if the contents of the file are displayed.  Because, that's what your JavaScript is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is plain text then you can easily fetch it with jQuery. Setting data type to text will ensure jQuery does not try to process it as something else. Adding an error handler will help catch errors.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "load.cst",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "text"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  console.error( "Request failed: ", textStatus );
});
```